# What kind of authentication mechanism to use for my REST based API service?

Tags: node.js, restful-authentication

I am making a small Rest based webservice. I have used OAuth and other authentication mechanism before but never implemented one by myself. Can some one give direction on how to do this in either NodeJs or even in any other framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth). It has a lot of examples inside that repo.

Besides of that OAuth I would use some api-key auth (maby generated in your online service). And of course limit the access - protect your servers from too large traffic from a single api-key.

Comment: I don't want oAuth consumer.. I need oAuth provider.